# Error handling for FetchURL() domain search Google Scripts App

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script that works well when the returned search has a domain prefix of "www.". How can I build in error handling for when "www." is not there. Also, bonus question: My script returns the first search result. Sometimes that is wikipedia or linkedin, but I only want the company's domain name returned.

Current Script:

```
function fetchURL(input) {

  var input = "Southwest Airlines";
  var url = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=what+is+the+website+for+"+encodeURIComponent(input);

  var options = {
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true
  };

  var searchResults = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var titleExp = /<h2 class=\"result__title"\>([\s\S]*?)<\/h2>/gi;
  var titleResults = searchResults.getContentText("UTF-8").match(titleExp);

  // return the first match 
  var results = decodeURIComponent(titleResults[0]);
  console.log(results);

  let domain = results.split("www.")[1].split("/")[0];
  console.log(domain);

  return domain;

}
```

For 'Southwest Airlines' this script will return southwest.com. However, for 'City of Houston' it errors out because the first search result is a wikipedia page AND it's en.wikipedia.org with no "www".

Answer (score 1):

- You want to achieve the following situations using Google Apps Script.

  - When `Southwest Airlines` is put to the variable of `input`, you want to return the value of `southwest.com`.
  - When `City of Houston` is put to the variable of `input`, you want to return the value of `en.wikipedia.org`.

#### Modification points:

- In this answer, I modified `let domain = results.split("www.")[1].split("/")[0]`.

  - the value is retrieved using the regex.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
let domain = results.split("www.")[1].split("/")[0];
```

To:

```
const temp = results.match(/https?:\/\/(www.)?(.+?)\//);
let domain = temp.length == 2 ? temp[1] : temp.length == 3 ? temp[2] : "No match";
```

#### Note:

Unfortunately, I'm not sure about other values of `input`. I tested this for `Southwest Airlines` and `City of Houston`.

Comment: Actually, I always want to return the company's actual domain. So it should be houstontx.gov for the City of Houston. It's returning the first search result which may not always be the right domain. Thanks for the updated code. I will give it a try during my journey.

Comment: @BigMike Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, when `City of Houston` is used for `input`, it seems that the value of `houstontx.gov` is not included in the values from `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)` which used your endpoint. How about this?

Comment: Hi @BigMike , so you basically want to find the url or domain that will match a specific domain right (in this case .gov) from the whole search?

Comment: @ Mateo Randwolf - My main goal is to search a list of Company Names and find the domain name for that company.

Comment: Then I believe your question is not so much Apps Script related but how to look for a verification of the list of sites appearing on your search. Also, as it is another question apart from the one @Tanaike solved, I recommend you asking it in a new question. Maybe changing how you ask the question ```what+is+the+website+for+``` might help. By the way, in the ```City of Houston``` case I am getting as the first result the correct one.